# Calculate average based on dates value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with a date and rating.  A little excerpt looks like this

```
array(111) {
 [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2018-03-03 17:15:42"
    ["rating"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2018-02-24 09:56:03"
    ["rating"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2018-02-22 12:46:44"
    ["rating"]=>
    int(5)
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is calculate the average rating for each month.  At the moment, I am trying like this

```
foreach($row as $val){
    $result[substr($val['date'],0,7)] += $val['rating'];
}
```

Obviously at the moment this is only adding up the values for each month, I then need to divide it but the number of rows within each month.  I am not too sure how I can do this.  I am also unsure as to whether what I am doing above is the best way to achieve what I am after.

Additionally, with the above, I seem to get a lot of notices for each month saying

> Notice: Undefined index: 2012-05

But after all of these notices it does output the counts for each month.  Why would I be getting these notices?

Thanks

Comment: you get the notices when you first set a value for a month with this operator: `+=`. It's trying to add something that wasn't defined before. So to get rid of the notices you should check first if this month is there already, then add `+=`, else just set `=`

Comment: a combination of array_filter and array_reduce might also do the job.

Comment: kind of looks like it might be output from a db query, in which case you could just do the calculation at the database level.

Comment: I was actually thinking about inserting into a database first instead of using an array.  Would this make more sense?

Comment: well I dont know the full usage case, but its a simply query to retrieve the monthly averages.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [user3720435](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3720435/user3720435), you will need to initialize the sums to zero before adding anything. Then you still need to divide by the number of ratings per month to get the averages. This can be achieved by adding another map keeping track of these counts.

```php
foreach ($row as $val) {
  $key = substr($val['date'], 0, 7);
  if (!array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
    $result[$key] = 0;
    $count[$key] = 0;
  }
  $result[$key] += $val['rating'];
  $count[$key]++;
}

foreach ($row as $val) {
  $key = substr($val['date'], 0, 7);
  $result[$key] /= $count[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$result` index does not exist before trying to add to it. You need to add the array first.

```
foreach($row as $val){
  $key = substr($val['date'],0,7);
  if (!array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
    $result[$key] = 0;
  }
  $result[$key] += $val['rating'];
}
```